# Execute one async function at a time

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to serially execute async functions.  So, wait until the first one has finished before starting the next one.  To do this, I have created a boolean to serve as a type of lock which blocks until we are ready to execute the next function.

isExecuting gets set to true, but it is never set to false afterwards.  Do you see why?

Here is a test which I wrote.

```
test('Should execute serially', () async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final example = DoSynchronously();
  example.convertToSync();
});
```

Here is the example code:

```
class DoSynchronously {  

  static bool isExecuting = false;
  static const readDelay = 1000;

  void convertToSync() {
    while (true) {
      waitToExecute();
      isExecuting = true;
      anAsyncFunction();
    }
  }

  void waitToExecute() {
    while (isExecuting) {
      print("read delay");
      sleep(
        const Duration(milliseconds: readDelay),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> anAsyncFunction() async {
    startExecuting();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 'Delayed 2 seconds.')
        .then((result) => print(result));
    stopExecuting();
  }

  void startExecuting() {
    isExecuting = true;
    print("executing = true");
  }

  void stopExecuting() {
    isExecuting = false;
    print("Stopped executing");
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like the correct way to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Would Future.wait https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-async/Future-class.html or a Completer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html help?

Also if you want to set some bool to true at the start of a function and then set it to false at the end, you might want to add a try/catch block around the code you do in between to guarantee the bool gets reset even when an exception occurs.

Comment: [See documentation for sleep function](https://api.dart.cn/dev/2.13.0-59.0.dev/dart-io/sleep.html): "Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call."

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments - I'm a beginner in dart.  I'll try out both suggestions and post back here soon.

Comment: While you can serialize asynchronous function calls, you will never be able to convert asynchronous function calls to synchronous ones, which seems to be your intent.